# Images loaded in the canvas resemble video streaming in Anuglar

Tags: angular

Receive frames from the backend via sockets, create the blob URL, and render the images on the mobile canvas. These images load in the canvas, but it appears like video streaming in Angular.

Expected: images load in the canvas, but it appears like video streaming

````
 this.sessionSocket.SocketMessagesImage.subscribe((message) => {
   if (message.size > 4 && !this.showAssertionImage) {
     this.ngZone.run(() => {
       this.animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
         this.frameEmitted(message)
       );
     });
   }
 });
frameEmitted(frameData) {
 this.lastFrame = frameData;
 // Use URL.createObjectURL instead of FileReader for better performance
 const url = URL.createObjectURL(
   new Blob([frameData], { type: "image/jpeg" })
 );
 this.imageToDraw.src = url;
 // Release the previous URL if it exists
 if (this.previousUrl) {
   URL.revokeObjectURL(this.previousUrl);
 }
 this.previousUrl = url;

 this.imageToDraw.onload = (_event) => {
   const context = this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
   const resChanged =
     this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.height !== this.imageToDraw.height;
   this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.height = this.imageToDraw.height;
   this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.width = this.imageToDraw.width;
   if (resChanged) {
     if (this.imageToDraw.height < this.imageToDraw.width) {
       document
         .getElementById("canv-container")
         .classList.remove("device-portrait");
       document
         .getElementById("canv-container")
         .classList.add("device-landscape");
       this.WindowResized = true;
     } else {
       document
         .getElementById("canv-container")
         .classList.add("device-portrait");
       document
         .getElementById("canv-container")
         .classList.remove("device-landscape");

       this.WindowResized = true;
     }
   }
   context.drawImage(this.imageToDraw, 0, 0);
   if (this.WindowResized) {
     this.scaleScreen();
   }
 };
}```
````

Comment: please share code, if possible stackblitz to replicate the issue and expected result!

Comment: now u can check